# Blank Notification Banner Stuck in macOS Sierra

Tags: macbook-pro, bug

This blank notification banner appeared out of nowhere, at the top-right corner, and won't go away even if I restart/shutdown the MacBook, kill Dock, Finder or Notification Center. It won't appear if I boot in Safe Mode though. If I have two desktops open by using Spaces, only the first one will have this on, but if I close it, the banner will move to the second one.

Has anyone experienced something like that? I'm on a 13" MacBook Pro running macOS Sierra version 10.12.5.

[image]

Comment: Can you give an indication of where it is on your screen (e.g. top right, etc)? Also, what happens if you boot into Safe Mode (i.e. hold the `shift` key down as you boot up)? Does it still occur while in Safe Mode and also after restarting again normally? Also, what exact version of macOS Sierra are you running? Finally, have you updated/installed any software recently?

Comment: I have seen (ahem...) people playing tricks on each other by doing something to the desktop wallpaper (snapshotting the desktop and then hiding all icons...) have you tried changing the desktop background wallpaper?

Comment: @Monomeeth, it's at the top-right corner, I've updated the question now, sorry. I doesn't occur in Safe Mode, but comes back if I restart it normally. macOS Sierra version 10.12.5 and I haven't installed any software right before it appearing (it didn't even need a reboot to appear in first place).

Comment: @SteveChambers no, it is not a prank. I'm the only one who uses my laptop, and I know it is not a problem in my wallpaper anyway because if I open two desktops using Spaces, only the first one will have this on. I'm going to update the question with those answers now.

Comment: I had something similar a long time ago. What if you open Activity Monitor and look for an App that you may have removed. Perhaps something is left of it?

Comment: @SteveChambers, after some searching in the Activity Monitor I haven't found anything weird at all. Any other suggestions?

Comment: sorry, out of ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had the same Problem and disabled all Notifications with no result.
Then I tried stopping some apps and found that the "EthernetStatus Mini"-App was responsible for it.

[image]

EthernetStatus Mini running (Banner always appears when Starting EthernetStatus Mini)

[image]

EthernetStatus Mini stopped

Comment: The banner disappeared after some weeks (even though no OS updates have occurred) but you are probably right since I have EthernetStatus Mini installed.

Answer (score 5):

I had stuck notification w/ request to change password. And I killed it:

```
➜  ~ ps -ef|grep -i notif
    0   121     1   0 27Sep19 ??        38:04.27 /usr/sbin/notifyd
133241192  1067     1   0 27Sep19 ??         2:06.70 /System/Library/CoreServices/NotificationCenter.app/Contents/MacOS/NotificationCenter
➜  ~ kill 1067
```

Comment: Nice answer! Much better than the Apple forum answers asking to clean the disk.